# Qt childs are visible but parent not

Tags: qt, parent-child, visibility

I have some widgets, `QToolButtons` to be exactly, and I initialize them like this:

```
QFrame *frmBackground = new QFrame(ui->centralWidget);
QToolButton *btnMenueExit = new QToolButton(frmBackground);
```

But now my problem. When I call `frmBackground->setVisible(false)`, the child should disappear too, but thats not the case. The children are still visible and I would have to call `setVisible(false)` for every child. It's not like I can't do this, but I think I miss something essential about the concept of parent and child.

All of the widgets are organized in the same `QGridLayout`.

What concerns me is, that if I make the child<-->parent relationship in the designer, with dropping the child into the parent widget, the child is disappearing when I call `parent->setVisible(false)`;

Are there some other parameters I have to set to make these properties to be passed to the child, like a property binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QLayout` takes ownership of the widget, when you add one with `addWidget()`. Using `parent` argument in widget constructor is not necessary.

Setting one widget to be direct parent of another is not a good practice, you should always use layouts.

> If you want to use a QWidget to hold child widgets you will usually want to add a layout to the parent QWidget.

`setVisible()` propagates to all children. If it doesn't work for child widgets then the widget is not their parent (anymore).